# If there is no data to display then pass to next iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on HTML table and showing Images one after other, as the UI is bit complicated here I am showing How it is working

if there are more that one images than :-

- it is displaying as table-->image1-->table-->image2

if there is only one Image than table-->image1-->table->image2

So I am calling my Images from database so if there are Images present in db then I am calling JSON as `var images = {"": ["CountA1.jpg", "CountA2.jpg"], }`

If there is no data in db I am calling an empty JSON `var images = {"":[""]}`, so what I am trying to do when there is no i don't want to show that Images it should skip that image part, as for displaying table and images I have given some time there

- table will be on Ui for `5seconds` than Image also for `5seconds`, here when there is no data as I am getting empty Image it shows up image `alt value` and display it for 5 seconds which is not the case I want if no image that only table should populates like how it was populating as a gap of `5-5 seconds`

```js
var imgLen = 0;
var cnt = 0;

var tableValue = [{
  "Item Name": "MANCHOW  V SOUP",
  "SellingPrice": 100
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 650",
  "SellingPrice": 900
}, {
  "Item Name": "Chole Kulche",
  "SellingPrice": 80
}, {
  "Item Name": "Butter Nan",
  "SellingPrice": 65
}, {
  "Item Name": "Dhai",
  "SellingPrice": 20
}, {
  "Item Name": "Rice",
  "SellingPrice": 55
}, {
  "Item Name": "Plain rice",
  "SellingPrice": 30
}]


interval = '';
var images = {
  CounterA: ["CounterA1.jpg", "CounterA2.jpg"]
}
initTable(tableValue);

function initTable(tableValue) {
  addTable(tableValue)
  showRows();
  imageFormatter();
  interval = window.setInterval(showRows, 5000); // seting interval to show table in parts
}




function hideImage() {
  var imgno = (cnt % imgLen) + 1; // here counting Image when it is last image want to refresh the oage using location.reload();
  console.log(imgno)
  $("#displayImage img").css("display", "none");
  $("#displayImage img:nth-child(" + imgno + ")").css("display", "block")

  $("#displayImage").show(); //show Image and hide table
  $("#DisplayTable").hide();

  setTimeout(function() {
    initTable(tableValue);
  }, 5000);
  cnt++;
}





function showRows() {
  // Any TRs that are not hidden and not already shown get "already-shown" applies
  if ($(".hidden:lt(10)").length > 0) { //checking is it is the last page or not
    $("#displayImage").hide(); //showing table hiding image
    $("#DisplayTable").show();
    $("tr:not(.hidden):not(.already-shown)").addClass("already-shown");
  } else {
    $("tr:not(.hidden):not(.already-shown)").addClass("already-shown");

    hideImage();

    clearInterval(interval); //if last then clearing time interval and calling the function again 
  }

  $(".hidden:lt(10)").removeClass("hidden"); // this one is to hide previous  rows and show next 
}

function addTable(tableValue) {
  var $tbl = $("<table />", {
      "class": "table fixed table-bordered"
    }),
    $tb = $("<tbody/>"),
    $trh = $("<tr/>");

  var split = Math.round(tableValue.length / 4);
  for (i = 0; i < split; i++) {
    $tr = $("<tr/>", {
      class: "hidden w3-animate-zoom"
    });

    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      $.each(tableValue[split * j + i], function(key, value) {
        if (typeof(value) === "number") {
          $("<td/>", {
            "class": "text-right color" + (j + 1)
          }).html(value).appendTo($tr);
        } else {
          $("<td/>", {
            "class": "text-left color" + (j + 1)
          }).html(value).appendTo($tr);
        }

      });
    }
    $tr.appendTo($tb);
  }
  $tbl.append($tb);
  $("#DisplayTable").html($tbl);

}



function imageFormatter() {

  var images = {
    "": [""]
  }
  // var images = {"": ["CountA1.jpg", "CountA2.jpg"], }  

  for (var key in images) {

    var imageList = images[key];
    for (i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
      var img = $('<img />').attr({
        'src': 'Image/' + key + '/' + imageList[i], // this one is displaying Image one below other
        'alt': 'No Image to Display',
        'width': 90 + "%",
        'height': 680
      }).appendTo('#displayImage');
    }

  }
  imgLen = $("#displayImage img").length;
}
```

```css
tbody>tr>td {
  white-space: normal;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .9em;
}

td:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(4),
td:nth-child(6),
td:nth-child(8) {
  width: 85px;
  max-width: 85px;
  height: 63px
}

.fixed {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.color1 {
  background: #4AD184;
}

.color2 {
  background: #EA69EF;
}

.color3 {
  background: #E1A558;
}

.color4 {
  background: #F4F065;
}

.hidden,
.already-shown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="DisplayTable"></div>
<div id="displayImage" style="display:none">

</div>
```

If any other JSON format required than I can call that, I just want to make it don't display Image when there is no Image